# geom_contour on adjusted number of distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot of Gaussian distributions that are included in `samp`, but the size of `samp` may varies. Here there are 4 components but it may there are less or more components. How could I adjust the code two plot as many components as there are in `samp`?

```
  ggplot(samp, aes(x=seq1, y=seq2)) + 
    geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.1), color = "tomato") + 
    geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.2), color = "darkblue") + 
    geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.3), color = "green4") + 
    geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.4), color = "purple") +
    labs(x = "PC1", y = "PC2", title="Posterior probability") +
    theme_bw()
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is probably to pivot all columns whose names include the string "prob" into long format. That way, it's also easy to map the name of each probability to the color aesthetic, which gives you the option of a legend:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(pivot_longer(samp, contains("prob")), aes(seq1, seq2, colour = name)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = value)) +
  labs(x = "PC1", y = "PC2", title="Posterior probability") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Sample data used**

```r
set.seed(1)

samp <- setNames(as.data.frame(replicate(4, rnorm(100))), paste0("prob.", 1:4))
samp$seq1 <- rep(1:10, 10)
samp$seq2 <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
```